# How to detect merged blobs?

Tags: opencv, split, blob, cvblobslib

I'm wondering if there is a method to detect two blobs being split or being merged ?
is there an OpenCV or CVblob  built-in functions to do the task if not any hint will be nice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If these blobs are moving in video, then it is tracking issue. You can use kalman filter or particle filter ( good tutorial on tracking here: http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUxiT_SKEUs1oWT6i9P3vPQ ). You also can use optical flow as additional color channels (x and y velosity components) for blobs separation.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, please let me be more precise; a moving person that dropped something and i have to detect the owner, i have done some research and all it seems that Action recognition is the solution, but i was wondering if there is a Blob level solution.